# Nested <ul> tags in HTML to XML conversion using XSLT

Tags: html, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have these nested `<ul>` tags. What I want to do is convert some of them to `<para>` tags. 
So I have this code:

```
<xsl:template match="ul">
<para>
<xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
</para>
</xsl:template>
```

My problem is that when I have nested `<ul>` tags it will create a `<para>` for all of them- so if I have `<ul><ul>` it will create `<para><para>`. How do I make it create only one `<para>` when it's a `<ul>` nested in another `<ul>` or any other tag, or nothing at all?

**Sample XML input:**

yes- So I have something like `<ul>A. The definition of "Panoply" is:</ul>` and then `<ul><ul>A Large assortment</ul></ul>`. I want to make the double `<ul>` into a `<blockquote>`, but it's already picking up `<para>` from the other template and the dtd I am working with doesn't allow blockquotes in paras

**another edit**

basically what I am looking to do is remove two tags instead of one. If I write

```
<xsl:template match="ul/ul">
<xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

it will only remove the second `<ul>`, how do I remove both?

my expected output for the sample input above would be

```
<para>A. The definition of "Panoply" is:</para>
<blockquote>A Large assortment</blockquote>
```

instead of

```
<para>A. The definition of "Panoply" is:</para>
<para><para>A Large assortment</para></para>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your input XML with nest UL elements? Thanks!

Comment: the code still validates with multiple <para> tags, and it displays, but I don't want to have multiple empty <para> tags in the file- it's not necessary and makes it look just not right

Comment: It would also be helpful to see a sample of the expected output. I'm not clear on what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```
<xsl:template match="ul">
    <para>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </para>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul[ul]">
    <blockquote>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|ul/node()"/>
    </blockquote>
</xsl:template>
```

The second template matches only `ul`s that have `ul` children and processes only the content of these children. The first template matches all other `ul` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are shown us so far suggests you are on the write track. For example, consider the following XML

```
<body>
   <ul>A. The definition of "Panoply" is:</ul> 
   <ul>
      <ul>A Large assortment</ul>
   </ul>
</body>
```

If you put the two templates you have shown us into an XSLT, then your XSLT may look like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="ul">
      <para>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
      </para>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ul/ul">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And when this is applied to the above XML, the following is output

```
<body>
   <para>A. The definition of "Panoply" is:</para>
   <para>A Large assortment</para>
</body>
```

It is worth reading about [resolving template conflicts](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#conflict) at this point. In your case this means the template matching **ul/ul** will always be matched before the template matching just **ul**.

But you also wanted a rule about replacing a "double ul" with a block-quote. In which case, just add the following template to the above XML

```
<xsl:template match="ul[ul]">
   <blockquote>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
   </blockquote>
</xsl:template>
```

When the amended XSLT is applied to the XML, you should get the following output

```
<body>
    <para>A. The definition of "Panoply" is:</para>
    <blockquote>A Large assortment</blockquote>
</body>
```

It is worth pointing out though, back on the subject of template conflict, if you had **ul** elements nested to three elements, like so

```
<ul>
   <ul>
     <ul>A Large assortment</ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Then the middle **ul** would be matched by both the **ul/ul** and **ul[ul]** templates, and this would be considered an error unless you speficied a priority on the templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can  have special match rules for elment up
 -  with parent ul element

```
<xsl:template match="ul[name(parent::*) = 'ul']">
```

- and with ul child elment

```
<xsl:template match="ul[name(child::*[1]) = 'ul']" >
```

Something like this should do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="ul">
        <para>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul[name(child::*[1]) = 'ul']" >
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul[name(parent::*) = 'ul']">
        <blockquote><xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/></blockquote>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```